# Unable to schedule job in VM using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am scheduling QTP scripts using Jenkins, intended to run on weekends. The QTP scripts are in the same Jenkins machines.

The build is not ***triggered*** at the scheduled time instead it triggers only when I login to the VM as it seems so.

**Configuration:**
OS : Windows 7 Ultimate
Jenkins version: 1.620 (master only)

When I do build manually, it works. Only the scheduling is not working.

Comment: _"Remote"_ from _where_? Is this the Jenkins master or a slave of it? Which OS? How do you connect remotely? What's the content of **Build triggers** → Build periodically → Schedule? Is the job in the **Build Queue** in the sidebar to the left prior to running?

Comment: @GeroldBroser I have updated the question. please have a look.thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jenkins Slave as a service, you have to make sure that it runs as administrator in services.msc in the Log On tab. Make sure to restart the service after you add the Admin Account.

Cheers!

Comment: Jenkins is running as master, but Log on as “Local System”. Is  log on as “Local System” is causing the issue, and does log on as “Network  service” will fix it?

Comment: log on as <administrator> will fix it